# Elegant way to find if a class instance is contained in a std::vector (C++)

Tags: c++, std

I want to construct a vector that will hold `int M` elements of my class `Point` which represent a single point (x,y) where both x,y are `int`.

The points that will be stored in this vector are randomly generated. However, I do not want to store the same point more than once.

My implementation is the following:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());

std::vector<Point> InitList(int M)
{
  if ( M <=0 )
    {
      std::cout << "InitList: Length of vector must be greater than zero. Don't play around!"
        << std::endl;
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  Point to_erase(-100,-100);    // <----- can I get rid of this?
  Point to_add;
  int x,y;
  std::vector<Point> vec = {}; 
  vec.push_back(to_erase);      // <----- and this
  
  while (vec.size() < M+1)      // <----- and then M+1 -> M
    {
      std::uniform_int_distribution<int> RandInt(0,100);
      x = RandInt(mt);
      y = RandInt(mt);
      point.set(x,y);
      if ( std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(),to_add) == vec.end() )
    vec.push_back(to_add);
    }
  vec.erase (vec.begin());     // <----- and finally avoid this?
  return vec;  
}
```

How can I avoid the trick of adding the first instance `to_erase`?

*******EDIT*******

So I changed the implementation to use `std::unordered_set`
and I am getting the following errors:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::unordered_set<_Value, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_set() [with _Value = Site; _Hash = std::hash<Site>; _Pred = std::equal_to<Site>; _Alloc = std::allocator<Site>]’

note: ‘std::hash<Site>::hash()’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  101 |     struct hash : __hash_enum<_Tp>
      |            ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/functional_hash.h:101:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__hash_enum<Site, false>::__hash_enum()’
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/functional_hash.h:82:7: note: candidate: ‘std::__hash_enum<_Tp, <anonymous> >::__hash_enum(std::__hash_enum<_Tp, <anonymous> >&&) [with _Tp = Site; bool <anonymous> = false]’
   82 |       __hash_enum(__hash_enum&&);
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

And the list goes on. I guess there is an implementation missing in my class `Point`. What should I do?

Comment: Just use `std::set`, it will handle elements being unique, after you generate enough elements just initialize a vector with set data.

Comment: unordered_set seems like a good fit here. otherwise you can also keep your vector always sorted during insertion, then binary search the element before inserting and don't insert if already found.

Comment: Why do you have and add `to_erase` at all?

Comment: @aschepler well I thought it is not needed, but it won't work otherwise

Comment: You could use `std::find`, it's kind of elegant.  If the vector is sorted, you could use `std::binary_search` (which returns found/not found).  If you want the position to the item, use `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound`.  These may be considered more elegant than `std::find`.  You should review the standard algorithms library.  There are probably more elegant methods, but are they worthwhile?

Comment: @Angelos An unordered_set is basically a hash set, thus the container requires that a hash function must be defined for your key type.  Since `Point` does not have such a function defined for itself, you get the error.  I am assuming you know about hash sets and hash tables, and thus know what a "hash function" and other terminology means.  You can do a search on StackOverflow as to how to provide a hash function for the Point type.  Since Point mostly consists of two simple int values, a hash for this should be easy to come up with.

Answer (score 2):

You can guarantee uniqueness just by using `std::set` (https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) instead of `std::vector`.

If order doesn't matter, use `std::unordered_set`.

Regarding the `hash` issues you're seeing -- you have to define a hash function for a custom type, when using a few C++ types like `set`, `unordered_set`, `map`, etc. This is a function that returns a unique number based on the value of your custom `Point` instance. I stubbed out this example to give you an idea of how this might work for you, but YMMV:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

struct Point
{
  int x;
  int y;
  
  Point(int x, int y): x(x), y(y) {}; 
};

bool operator==(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs)
{
    return ((lhs.x == rhs.x) and (lhs.y == rhs.y));
}

namespace std
{
    template <>
    struct hash<Point>
    {
        size_t operator()( const Point& p ) const
        {
            return (p.x << 32 | p.y);
        }
    };
}


int main() {
  
    Point p1(3,2);
    Point p2(3,2);
  
    std::unordered_set<Point> someSet;

    someSet.insert(p1);
    
    std::cout << "set size:" << someSet.size() << std::endl;
    // set size: 1
    
    someSet.insert(p2);

    std::cout << "set size:" << someSet.size() << std::endl;
    // set size: 1 (still!)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, the order is irrelevant.

Comment: since ordering doesn't matter at all, why not unordered_set?

Comment: Thanks! I corrected that -- I said "if not", instead of "if so".

Comment: @Angelos -- Are you sure that order is not relevant?  Or to be more explicit, since you want randomness, isn't the random order of the numbers part of your design?  Do you really want to end up with `1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13`, etc. or `2, 10, 11, 8, 3, 13, 1, 7` (for example)?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No. Later I will generate randomly a point, and then look if it belongs to this set and treat it differently than others if it does.

Comment: I edited my initial post, can you take a look?

Comment: @Angelos -- see above.

Comment: One more question. The function ```InitList``` is in another file. Is there a way to avoid putting the extension of the std namespace in both my ```main.cpp``` and the ```functions.cpp```?

Comment: The hash function is a template function, so it can be included in any .hpp file you choose (you should put it with your Point definitions, though). If you have those in, say, point.hpp, then you don't need to include that chunk of code anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

If only presence is relevant:  `std::set`.

If you need also occurrence count, you could use  `std::map<Point, int>`, where the `int` is the count. With some special handling to remove elements when counts gets to zero.

You could replace `std::map` with `std::unordered_map` for performance reasons. But **ALWAYS** test both before deciding.